# Using feedparser to get streaming data

Tags: python, python-requests, feedparser

I am trying parse feeds like the following:

```
feed1 = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson'
feed2 = 'http://developer.usa.gov/1usagov'
```

I can use the feedparser module to parse the first feed, but not the second.

```
import feedparser
feed1_read = feedparser.parse(feed1) # doesn't hang
feed2_read = feedparser.parse(feed2) # hangs
```

Is there something I'm not understanding about how these feeds work? Why does feedparser hang on the second feed, but not the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feedparser` can't actually parse *either* of those feeds.  The [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) module is for parsing Atom and RSS feeds, which are XML document formats, while boths of those feeds return JSON documents.

After you call:

```
feed1_read = feedparser.parse(feed1) # doesn't hang
```

You will find that `feed1_read['feed']` is empty:

```
>>> feed1_read['feed']
{}
```

And also:

```
>>> feed1_read['bozo_exception']
SAXParseException('Document is empty\n',)
```

Possibly the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module will be more useful.

Comment: Perfect! I simply do `r = requests.get(link1,stream = True)`